# How to run a JUnit test programatically

Tags: java, junit

I am writing a custom tool that executes a set of test classes programmatically using JUnit 5.

When executing these tests, how does one get their actual output printed out to the console, or to a log file?

I have roughly the following code:

```
LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
        .selectors(selectPackage(basePackage))
        .filters(includeClassNamePatterns(classNamePatterns))
        .build();

SummaryGeneratingListener listener = new SummaryGeneratingListener();

Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();
launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(listener);

TestPlan testPlan = launcher.discover(request);

// launcher.execute(request);
launcher.execute(testPlan);

TestExecutionSummary summary = listener.getSummary();
summary.printTo(new PrintWriter(System.out));
summary.printFailuresTo(new PrintWriter(System.out));
```

I've tried it with just the request and a test plan. I'm not quite sure what the difference between the two is, but the result appears to be the same:

```
Test run finished after 50 ms
[         3 containers found      ]
[         0 containers skipped    ]
[         3 containers started    ]
[         0 containers aborted    ]
[         3 containers successful ]
[         0 containers failed     ]
[         2 tests found           ]
[         0 tests skipped         ]
[         2 tests started         ]
[         0 tests aborted         ]
[         2 tests successful      ]
[         0 tests failed          ]
```

...Which is great -- my two tests are being picked up and executed programmatically (I have specifically changed their suffixes from `Test` to `Probe` and manually specified that it should use the `.*Probe` pattern and it is definitely running them as I have no other tests.

I am, however, not getting any output. I assume I'm missing some listener, or haven't set a parameter or something...? Please, advise! Thanks!

Comment: This? https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0/api/org/junit/platform/launcher/listeners/LoggingListener.html

Comment: @BoristheSpider: So, how is this used exactly?

Comment: @carlspring `launcher.execute(LoggingListener.forJavaUtilLogging())`